# What does Amp of a function mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading a proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem where the author writes the following

> "$w$ is continuous on $K$ and does not vanish, and therefore $\mathrm{Amp}
>  \; w$ is defined everywhere".

The notation $\mathrm{Amp}$ is never given a meaning in the text however. What does it denote?
[source](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-9/issue-2/An-elementary-proof-of-Brouwers-fixed-point-theorem/10.2748/tmj/1178244835.full)

Comment: It would help enormously if you named / linked to the source.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a typo for map?

Comment: Maybe Amplitude?!

Comment: I found [this](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdffirstpage_1&handle=euclid.tmj/1178244835) by Googling parts of the quote. From the context, it appears to be a synonym for "argument".   Further Googling reveals that sometimes "amplitude" is (or was) used in this way, but that is news to me.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, he included the source, Tohoku 1956. He does the case of two dimensions in the complex plane and is clearly using argument.

Answer (score 5):

It is a synonym for argument in the complex plane. Not one any of us knew.

[image]